# Copper wire in municipal water piping foam insulation?

Tags: sensor

A couple years ago the municipality upgraded the water piping in part of the town. I couldn't help but notice while walking nearby that the new pipes had small gauge, insulated, solid core copper wires (similar to the ones in CAT5 cables) coming out the foam insulation, likely attached to some kind of sensor. I'm very curious what those are for. I mean pipes of this kind:

[image]

Comment: Leaks in buried water systems are nasty to deal with and often persist for years, so could be some sort of humidity sensor to detect if there's an internal or external leak into the space filled by the foam, could actually be some sort of data network for (or taking advantage of) the installation...

Answer (score 3):

I thought the wire was so that they could locate the cable with a magnetometer or some other sensor.  When pipes were all galvanized metal, that wasn't a problem.  But with most new municipal water systems going to PVC or something similar, they needed a way to be able to locate their pipes.  Hence the addition of the wire.